# React-Native - Could not connect to development server (iOS simulator)

Tags: react-native

```
Error:

Could not connect to develpment server.

Ensure the following:
- Node server is running and available on the same network - run 'npm start' from react-native root
- Node server URL is correctly set in AppDelegate

URL: http://127.0.0.1:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true
```

I definitely am running npm start.  Why isn't this running?

Now I am seeing this Error:

```
In file included from /Users/*******/f8app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/ios/RCTFBSDK/core/RCTFBSDKAccessToken.m:19:
/Users/*********/f8app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/ios/RCTFBSDK/core/RCTFBSDKAccessToken.h:21:9: fatal error: 
      'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
```

Comment: Can you access that URL in your browser?

Comment: no, it refuses to connect: 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.

Comment: however, I am able to get to http://localhost:8080/dashboard/apps and http://localhost:8080/graphql just fine and those come up.

Answer (score 1):

Does the project build succeed in Xcode?

Did you double-check these steps mentioned by facebook:

- Make sure that the Facebook SDK frameworks are installed in
  ~/Documents/FacebookSDK.
- Make sure that FBSDK[Core, Login, Share]Kit.framework show up in the
  Link Binary with Libraries section of your build target's Build
  Phases.
- Make sure that ~/Documents/FacebookSDK is in the Framework Search
  Path of your build target's Build Settings.
  (https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk)

I myself had some troubles with the final step, but after retrying in a fresh project all worked fine

[Example image from web showing the correct search path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yso8k.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the project build doesn't succeed, you may want to try this.
You should first update your existing FBSDK (if any)

https://medium.com/@alberto.schiabel/react-native-on-xcode-beta-8-0-how-to-fix-initial-build-error-f0225c649850#.439zl5504